# dc.js - onClick to grab key value

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm trying to get the key value when clicking on a bar chart in dc.js (I want to use this value when opening a new page)
I've used the following (commented out bits!) but cannot get the key value I'm after, I thought it would be d.key? What am I missing?

```
 chart.renderlet(function(chart) {
   chart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function(d) {
     console.log("click!", d);
     //   return d.key;
     // id=d.key;
     // window.location = "information.php?id="+id;
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not famililar with `dc.js`, but looking at the source to [this](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/bar.html), tt would be:

```
d.data.key
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OWLStxfPMtDuZeHHvvH1?p=preview).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what is the selected element of a  GeoChoroplethChart such that I can then center the map around it, here's the map I'm working with `smenglish.github.io/dash_snow`, I thought this would be applicable, but- seems not. am I wrong about that? Do you know what would be a good solution to that problem?